# How to remove crayon off the wall?

Tags: stain-removal

I'm doing a project I have to make a spray that erases crayon off the wall without removing the original paint.

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking us to invent a new product for you?

Comment: Homework for shop class? It sounds like you are tasked with finding something that reacts with or dissolves wax, but does not react with paint. If such chemicals or compounds exist, they should be easy to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 results from Googling for "remove crayon from walls" yields:

[Reader's Digest](http://www.rd.com/slideshows/how-to-get-crayon-off-the-wall/) has several suggestions.
[TipNut](http://tipnut.com/21-crayon-busters-how-to-remove-crayon-from-walls/) has several suggestions.
[About.com](http://housekeeping.about.com/od/surfaceswalls/tp/crayonwalls.htm) has several suggestions.

Or are you looking to invent something new?